# Linux Mint 17.1 Mate stops responding

Tags: linux, linux-mint, debugging

I was using LM 17.1 Mate version quite smoothly until one day I found my desktop wallpaper had changed to the original. Then after refreshing for 2nd time it keeps on refreshing and it seems that my cursor doesn't highlight icons when it is over them.

Also single or double click won't work. Start menu responds but other icons on desktop won't. Also, after forcing shutdown I get file manager is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by updating the system.
Seems like they shipped the buggy kernel version.
Working smoothly afterwards!